# Property of the characteristic function for events

Tags: characteristic-functions

We got to show the following equality:

$1_{A_1 \cup...\cup A_n} = 1 - \prod \limits_{i=1}^n (1 - 1_{A_i})$

First I would like to ask for hints for how to proove this equation (no solution though, I would like to solve it myself). Secondly I was wondering if there is an "intuitive" interpretation of this equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. De Morgan's law for Boolean algebras:

> $A\cup B=(A^c\cap B^c)^c$

where $X^c$ denotes the complement set.
That's the hint.

Comment: When I understand it correctly then, the above equality can be shown as follows to hold: 
Either $x \in A_1 \cup .. \cup A_n$ or $x \notin A_1 \cup ... \cup A_n$. In accordance with the left side the right side then will be either 1 in the first case or 0 in the last case.

Comment: The complement corresponds to the unary operation $f\mapsto 1-f$ and the intersection corresponds to multiplication among characteristic functions.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful remark. I understand :-)